# Continuity of $m(E\cap B(x,r))$ with respect to $r.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-continuity

I was a little curious about continuity of the lebesgue measure. There was a question about showing that for all $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $0<m(E)<\infty,$ to show that for all $a\in(0,1)$ there exists $I$ an interval with $m(E\cap I)=am(I)$. I was thinking to by Lebesgue Differentiation choosing a point $x$ with 
$$m(E\cap B(x,r))/m(B(x,r))\to 1.$$
Then as $m(E)$ is finite, we can choosing $n$ large we find
$$m(E\cap B(x,r))/m(B(x,r))<a.$$
Now assuming continuity with respect to $r$ the desired result should just be the intermediate value theorem, correct?

Comment: Are you asking whether $m(E \cap B(x,r))$ is continuous as a function of $r$?  This is easy because if $0 \le r_1 < r_2$, $0 \le m(E \cap B(x, r_2)) - m(E \cap B(x, r_1)) \le m(B(x, r_2)) - m(B(x, r_1)) = 2 (r_2 - r_1)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's what I was asking. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Why is this true? I do not see how this follows ...

Comment: @WolfgangKrull which "this" are you asking about?